# Can't capture cmd.Run() stdout, stderr is fine

Tags: go, concurrency

This simple python script generates stdout/stderr messages, two per second.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, time
for a in range(10):
    if(a%2==0): print(a, file=sys.stdout)
    else: print(a, file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(0.5)
print("This is an STDOUT message")
print("This is an STDERR message", file=sys.stderr)
sys.exit(1)
```

Example output:

```
> ./runstatus.py 
0    <- STDOUT, after 0.5s
1    <- STDERR, after 0.5s
2    <- STDOUT, after 0.5s
3    ...
4
5
6
7
8
9
This is an STDOUT message     <- STDOUT
This is an STDERR message     <- STDERR
```

I need to capture the stdout and stderr outputs in realtime with golang, so I found moreover this:

```golang
package main
import("bufio"; "fmt"; "os/exec";)
func readerr(scanner *bufio.Scanner, channel string) {
    for scanner.Scan() { fmt.Println(channel, scanner.Text()); }
}
func main() {
    cmd:=exec.Command("./runstatus.py")
    stdout, _:=cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderr, _:=cmd.StderrPipe()
    scanout:=bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanerr:=bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
    scanout.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    scanerr.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    go readerr(scanout, "out:")
    go readerr(scanerr, "err:")
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

But the problem is this just works with STDERR!!! Stderr goes in realtime, but stdout not, it bumps suddenly at the end of the execution:

```
err: 1    <- STDERR, after 1s
err: 3    <- STDERR, after 1s
err: 5
err: 7
err: 9
out: 0    <- STDOUT, after 5s, from here, the rest just flushes abruptly!
out: 2
out: 4
out: 6
out: 8
out: This is an STDOUT message
err: This is an STDERR message
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you ignored every single error value.  This is a very bad idea, as - unlike say python - Go does not raise exceptions on error.  The error return values are the only mechanism you have to catch errors, so ignoring them really shoots you in the foot when debugging.  Get out of the habit of ignoring errors right away.  I'm not saying it's causing your current issue but it's a huge time waster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is that in Python the `print` output to stdout is buffered. The solution may depend on the Python version.

For example, run a script with the -u option

```bash
python -u ./runstatus.py
```

Since Python 3.3, the `print` function has a `flash` parameter, you can try using it:

```py
print(a, file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```

Comment: Correct, the problem was not with Golang, but with the Python buffered output. Everyday, something new under the sun. :)